# Why won't my program open? The code says there are no errors, but these two classes won't open together

Tags: java, android, function, android-activity, runtime-error

These two classes send methods and variables back and forth to each other and my code says there's no errors, but the program won't open and I can't figure out why

Here's the first class, `TopLevelActivity`

```
package com.example.oife;

import android.media.Image;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TopLevelActivity extends Activity {

    TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);


    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_oife);

        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

        TextView displayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(date);
        displayDate.setText(dateString);
    }
   public void onPostClick (View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //call onHomeClick() method when the button is clicked
    public void onHomeClick (View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TopLevelActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //call onMoreClick() method when the button is clicked
    public void onMoreClick(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public TextView getMainText(){
        return mText;
    }

    public void setMText(TextView t){
        mText.setText(t.getText());
    }

}
```

Here's the second class, `PostActivity`

### This class is where most of the functions from the other one are accessed

```
package com.example.oife;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class PostActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView pDisplayDate;
    private Button pPickDate;
    private int pYear;
    private int pMonth;
    private int pDay;
    private TextView mainText;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    private TextView day;

    TopLevelActivity top = new TopLevelActivity();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        /** Capture our View elements */
        pDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);
        pPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

        /** Listener for click event of the button */
        pPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        /** Get the current date */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        /** Display the current date in the TextView */
       // updateDisplay();

    }

   private void setMainText(){
        TextView d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

        mainText.setText(top.getMainText() + "/n/n" + name + "/n" + makeDay().getText() + "/n" + d.getText());

    }

    private TextView makeDay(){
        TextView ToD;
        RadioGroup t = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.TOD);
        int id = t.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(id == -1) {
            ToD = null;
        }
        else{
         ToD = (TextView) findViewById(id);
        }

        TextView wow;
        RadioGroup g = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.WoW);
        id = g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (id == -1){
            //no item selected
        }
        else{
            wow = (TextView) findViewById(id);
        }

        TextView d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);

        String s = String.valueOf(d);
        String j;
        if (ToD.getText().equals("Morning")){
            j = "9:00";
        }
        else if(ToD.getText().equals("Midday")){
            j = "12:00";
        }
        else if (ToD.getText().equals("Evening")){
            j = "5:00";
        }
        else {
            j = "10:00";
        }

        TextView time = new TextView(this);

        time.setText( j + " " + s);

        return  time;

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    pYear = year;
                    pMonth = monthOfYear;
                    pDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                    displayToast();
                }
            };

    private void updateDisplay() {
        pDisplayDate.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        // Month is 0 based so add 1
                        .append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
                        .append(pDay).append("/")
                        .append(pYear).append(" "));
    }

    private void updateMainDisplay(){

        setMainText();

        top.setMText(mainText);

    }

    private void displayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Date choosen is ").append(pDisplayDate.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}



    /** Create a new dialog for date picker */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        pDateSetListener,
                        pYear, pMonth, pDay);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onCreateClick(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TopLevelActivity.class);
        updateMainDisplay();
        startActivity(intent);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call code like this after you call `setContentView`:

Activity 1:

```
TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

Activity 2:

```
private TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

you did that wrong in both `Activitys`. You call `findViewById` in the member section of your `Activitys` and at this point the `Activity` dont know anything about the layout file.

That must leads to a `NullpointerException`.

Comment: Ok, I got the first activity to work, but now when I click the button leading to the second activity, the program stops.  Thanks for your help!